# No results showing for String NULL data in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I have an external table in hive which was loaded with some NULL data.

None of the below queries are returning any results:

```
select * FROM  db.table where bankrupt IS NULL;

select * FROM  db.table where bankrupt = '';

select * FROM  db.table where bankrupt = ' ';
```

But `select DISTINCT length(bankrupt) FROM  db.table;`
Is returning value 1.

Sample data:
(provided by client)
`295.12|31/12/2021| | |`

Bankrupt is the last column.

Comment: Can you try WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(bankrupt)) = ''? Maybe there is some special character in that field with lenght 1...

Comment: to add to @mbd's answer, it can be many spaces or special character that you can not see or hue can not display.

Comment: LTRIM, RTRIM didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT length(bankrupt) FROM  db.table;
```

If what you said is true, and this row returns only 1 value, it means that either you only have only one single defined value. Or you only have null values, neitherless. If you are sure there is null values, maybe is just a tiny syntax inconvenience. Because your line of code is correct

```
SELECT * FROM DF WHERE bankrupt IS NULL;
```